# Double iteration in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there an idiomatic way, in Scala, to express the following Java iteration

```
int n = 10;
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in the `...` part? There might be a more idiomatic way to do whatever you're trying to. (See also [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup,

```
for{
  i <- 0 until 9
  j <- i+1 until 10
} {
  //stuff goes here
}
```

Just like that.

Comment: Don't you need semicolon?

Comment: @Basilevs you would Iff they were on the same line. Here, I'm using `{}` instead of `()` so I do not need to include it as it's parsed as two distinct lines

Comment: @wheaties, `to` is inclusive on the right side. Make it `until`.

Comment: holy cow!  i had no idea you could use `{}` and drop the semicolon.  nice to learn something cool even from a pretty straightforward question.

Comment: Note that as of now, this is a bit slower than a raw while loop because it uses foreach and a closure under the hood. But Scala 2.11 will come with a new optimizer that, when enabled, should get the performance of a while loop out of this :-)

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn: you could already use [`Scalaxy`](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy/tree/master/Loops) for this optimization.

Comment: "But Scala 2.11 will come with a new optimizer " Cool. I've wanted this for ages. Any pointer to the details?